# Visual Studio 2017 Could not create directories, mkdir exit code: 1

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, visual-studio-2017

I have connected Visual Studio 2017 to SSH Server (Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash).

While compiling I got an error:

> F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2017\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.Common.targets(89,5): error : Could not create directories, mkdir exit code: 1

User in Ubuntu have permission to create directory.

Comment: Interesting question... A quick guess... Authentication is failing and you can't write to the filesystem. Maybe review [Visual C++ for Linux Development](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/) on MSDN.

Comment: Glad you solved it!  Would you please move the solution to an answer instead?  That way others will know you no longer need help.  After a few days, the system will let you accept that answer (the checkmark).  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more tips.  Happy hacking!

Comment: The same error, but with another reason and another solution:
[Move your project folder from Cloud-sync to common hard drive folder.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212898/visual-studio-2015-2017-could-not-create-directories-mkdir-exit-code-1-on-rasp/42891197#42891197)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install this:

   > sudo apt-get install openssh-server g++ gdb gdbserver
2. Reinstall ssh-server by this: https://superuser.com/questions/1111591/how-can-i-ssh-into-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10
3. Create new user and add this user to sudo group.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error happens because subsystem don't have home folder for current user. To create folder do this in terminal:

```
mkhomedir_helper username
```