# Visual Studio 2015/2017 Could not create directories, mkdir exit code: 1 on Raspberry

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2015, gdb, raspberry-pi3

Trying to connect remotely by Remote GDB Debugger in Visual Studio 2015 to Raspberry Pi 3 (ARM), but permanently got "Could not create directories, mkdir exit code: 1"

Tried the solution described on [Visual Studio 2017 Could not create directories, mkdir exit code: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389483/visual-studio-2017-could-not-create-directories-mkdir-exit-code-1) question, but still same.

I'm not "fluent" with Linux, so maybe It's just simple troubles with user adding or sudo groups modifying, but maybe someone made the same things successfully to explain?

Comment: See my answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389483/visual-studio-2017-could-not-create-directories-mkdir-exit-code-1?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Move project folder to common hard drive folder***

The mkdir error wasn't about linux user rights or SSH setup.
Considering than this command same in Windows and Unix, it was confusing to realize that issue was on client side, not on the linux target machine. The reason is than my project folder created on OneDrive folder, so it caused this access error (I don't know why), although I run Visual Studio with admin rights.

**So the solution was just to move project folder (e.g ConsoleApplication1) to common hard drive folder (Documents ets).**